# PHP and JSON/ How to get a specific elements //

Tags: php, json

I need to parse a JSON file. I've only worked with XML before.

How can I get the second "food_id" (1730905)?

Here is my JSON file:

```json
{
  "shopId":29,
  "last":46977914,
  "freshfood":[
    {
      "freshfood_id":2629,
      "food":[
        {
          "food_id":1740851,
          "type":"fruit",
          "status":1
        },
        {
          "food_id":1730905,
          "type":"vegetable",
          "status":1
        },
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried this, but it does not work.

```php
$string = file_get_contents("food.json");
$json_a=json_decode($string,true);
echo $GetFreshFoodId = $json_a['freshfood'][1]['freshfood_id'];
```

Comment: Your **JSON is invalid!**

Comment: You may want to clarify whether you're trying to get the "freshfood_id" or the second "food_id".

Comment: once you decode json, it's just a PHP data structure, like any other structure. you don't have a json array, you have a PHP array, and it's a php array like all other php arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP arrays are zero-based, so that should be:

```
$json_a['freshfood'][0]['food'][1]['food_id'];
```

Also, note that the JSON is not entirely valid - you should remove the last comma. (But you might have left out additional records in your example JSON for clarity.)

Comment: OP's JSON is invalid so he doesn't even have an array, which he can access.

Comment: He might've left additional records out for clarity.

Comment: Glorfindel, thank you very much. It's work. I can not mark your answer as useful, because I don't have reputation.

Comment: I'm glad to help - what you *could* do, is [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) the answer.